# Publish local .mp4 video from android to wowza using FFmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to publish a local .mp4 video from my sdcard to wowza using the ffmpeg java wrapper.

I have used the [library](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java) for executing ffmpeg commands on Android

On Android, my code looks as follows:

```
FfmpegController objController = new FfmpegController(MainActivity.this, new File("/tmp"));
                //objController.installBinaries(MainActivity.this,true);
                mFfmpegBin = objController.installBinary(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ffmpeg, "ffmpeg", true);
                //no just extract the audio
                ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();

                //-f dshow -i video="Integrated Camera" out.mp4
                cmd.add(mFfmpegBin);
                //cmd.add("-sample_fmts");
                cmd.add("-re");
                cmd.add("-i");      
                cmd.add("/sdcard/sample.mp4");
                cmd.add("-c");
                cmd.add("copy");
                cmd.add("-f");
                cmd.add("flv");
                cmd.add("rtsp://192.168.1.35:1936/live/myStream");

                objController.execFFMPEG(cmd, new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("shell out" + " "  +shellLine);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void processComplete(int exitValue) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("process complete::" + " " +exitValue);

                    }
                });

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Now, when I execute the command, I get the following logs

```
shell out Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/sdcard/sample.mp4':
shell out rtmp://192.168.1.35:1936/live/myStream: Protocol not found
```

Why is the protocol not supported on Android. When I run the same ffmpeg command from windows command line using ffmpeg then it works fine.

The command is,

ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.35:1936/live/myStream

Can please someone help?

Comment: You should show the complete output from `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Probably `librtmp` is not compiled/linked into your build.

Comment: how to link librtmp ? @Mulvya

Comment: FFmpeg has native RTMP support. Your commands vary. One is outputting to rtsp and the other rtmp. The complete console output will provide useful info.